# WooCommerce - Deleting the upper price on the product page with variations

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, customization

I would need to delete the price above the variations, under the product title, but ONLY in the product page, not on the main store page. I was not able to accomplish this. Is this possible with custom code?

[image]

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use css to hide price from product details page.

```
.type-product p.price {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know it's that simple.

Comment: yes, it is, above CSS is just applied only on the details page. not for other page